# Lightweight accordion script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a very lightweight [jQuery accordion](https://github.com/grantschulte/accordion-lite) with some tweaks and it's working nicely. Is there anything to improve?

**JS**

```
;(function($, doc, win) {
    "use strict";

    $.fn.accordionLite = function(){

        var sections = this.children(),
            trigger = sections.find('.accordion_trigger'),
            allContent = sections.find('.accordion_content');

        allContent.hide();
        $('.accordion_trigger.active').next('.accordion_content').show();

        trigger.click(function(){

            var activeContent = $(this).next('.accordion_content');

            if (activeContent.is(':hidden')) {
                allContent.slideUp('fast');
                activeContent.slideDown('fast');
                trigger.removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
            } else {
                allContent.slideUp('fast');
                trigger.removeClass('active');
            }

        });

    }

})(jQuery, document, window);
```

**Markup**

```
<ul class="accordion"> <!-- Accordion Element -->

    <li> <!-- Section Wrapper -->
        <a class="accordion_trigger">Trigger 1</a> <!-- Trigger -->
        <p class="accordion_content">Content Area 1</p> <!-- Content -->
    </li>

    <li>
        <a class="accordion_trigger">Trigger 2</a>
        <p class="accordion_content">Content Area 2</p>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a class="accordion_trigger">Trigger 3</a>
        <p class="accordion_content">Content Area 3</p>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is awesome code,

I would have added an s to `var trigger` since you are counting on more than 1 trigger.